# After copying sqlite file into Documents folder, the file getting empty

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I have a problem with .db file that after copying into Documents directory getting 0 KB of size, while the original file is 137KB. I tried to open my copied file in SQLite Manager. It opens, doesn't complaint about file corruption... It just doesn't contain a single table.

My code to copy the file:

```
- (void) createEditableDatabase
{
    BOOL success; 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSError *error;
    NSString *writableDB = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
    if (success)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSString *defaultPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"];
    error = nil;
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writableDB error:&error];
    if (!success) 
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Checks if file exist, if not copies. The check happens in RootViewController's

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.subCountriesArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
    NSMutableArray *subCountriesTemp=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];

    DBAccess *dbAccess=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
    [dbAccess createEditableDatabase]; //method to copy file
    subCountriesTemp=[dbAccess getSubCountries];

    [dbAccess closeDataBase];
    [dbAccess release];
}
```

So, that's strange for me. Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've solved this problem. In my DBAccess class I had method:

```
-(void)initializeDataBase
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];

   // NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        [self dbConnectionError];
    }
}
```

And it was called in init. -(void)initializeDataBase is fired at all. Now, this piece of code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"];
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

I call in every method separately. It helped.

Answer (score 7):

After all ,
I did like this.It worked for me.

1) click on the .db file.

2)then find the fileInspector on right side,click the file inspector

3) check the target membership of .db file whether checkbox is checked or not.

4)if not check the checkbox

Hope It will work...

Comment: But how could this really happens?
Because the .sqlite3 file has been copied to required Library folder, but without the DB Schema! And the reason here is seemed to be because it hadn't have the target membership. But if it hadn't have the target membership then how come it gets copied to the given path?

If you can please give a clue!
Thanks! You save a lot of time! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

How about you try it with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDB = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB] ) {
    NSString *databaseFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databaseFile toPath:writableDB error:nil];
    NSLog(@"database copied");
}
```

I don't think NSHomeDirectory is a valid way of accessing the documents directory....

Don't know for sure if this will solve it but it's worth a try.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I am still getting empty db

Comment: Are you sure it's a clean copy? My app somehow cached the database, even when I cleaned the app... i had to manually delete the app directory in order for it to install again...

Comment: I did it. I tried to delete on iphone simulator, them I deleted after another trial manually. nothing helps. every new fresh compilation brings me another 0KB database.

Comment: And if I am right, I cannot manually input the db file into documents directory. Right?

Comment: Weird... Well, pretty sure you checked this already. But the database you have in the NSMainBundle is the correct database and there is no writing to the database from the 'getSubCountries' method?

Comment: no. subCountries only reads from database. How to check if it's correct? I had no problems to read from it while it was in nsbundle.

Comment: yeah, you can copy the file to your /Users/{your name}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/{your application}/Documents directory... that's where it is all hiding... But that's only on the Mac obviously... The real app you have to copy it from the mainBundle... But it's worth checking if you copy it that it will not change once it's in the folder

Comment: Ha! Of cause it did help. In simulator I've got tableView populated I now my methods read/write work, but when I run the fresh copy on my device I do face the issue. I can't, and user too to change the database manually. That's the problem!

Comment: It didn't change the file. I opened and closed app several times. Changed file did work.

Comment: For some reason this  NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.db"]; line creates empty db in Documents directory. This line in method that checks if writable copy does exist NSString *writableDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"]; also does creates me db. And by the way yc_ch.db is not empty.

Comment: Looks like I need equivalent to NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"]; But now it should seek in documentsDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but if you copy a core data '.sqlite' database it also copies it empty, but there are two more files '.sqlite-shm' and '.sqlite-wal'.
If you copy those two more files with the same name of the destination with their respective extension the database is no longer empty.